# SQL matching rows as pairs from the same table when they have the same attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in my database, one for clients, one for products and one for orders, containing both the primary keys of products and clients as a foreign key. I am using SQL and MySQL

A query I'm struggling with is how to match two clients who bought the same product in 2014. They should also be displayed as c1.cname < c2.cname but that's not the important part.

I have tried the following:

`select c1.cname as c1name, c2.cname as c2name, p.pname from customers as c1 left outer join customers as c2 on c1.cid!=c2.cid inner join orders as o on o.cid=c1.cid=c2.cid inner join products as p on p.pid=o.pid where year(o.odate)=2014;`

Expected results using the following data would be :

```
c1name c2name pname

Jones   Smith   chocolate
Dupond  Gupta   sugar
Gupta   Jones   sugar
Jones   Smith   sugar
Dupond  Jones   milk
Jones   Smith   milk
Blake   Dupond  tea
Dupond  Gupta   tea
Gupta   Jones   tea
```

However, only one customer name is displayed in c2name for a reason I can't understand. Also, this customer is matched to customers having bought item number 6 when he never bought it himself.

In need of help and advice if anyone could help.

Here is the script for the database import:

```
create table products (

    pid         int,    
    
    pname       varchar(30) not null,

    price       decimal(7,2) not null check (price >= 0),

    origin      varchar(20),                          

    constraint products_pk primary key (pid)
);

create table customers (
    cid         int,

    cname       varchar(30) not null,

    residence   varchar(50),                          

    constraint customers_pk primary key (cid)

);

create table orders (
    pid         int,

    cid         int,

    odate       date not null,                          

    quantity    int not null check (quantity > 0),   

    constraint orders_pk primary key (pid, cid, odate),

    constraint orders_fk_pid foreign key (pid) references products (pid),

    constraint orders_fk_cid foreign key (cid) references customers (cid)

);
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Could you add to your question expected output for given data sample? That would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

The query I come up with may not produce the exact result format, but it still gives a similar answer.

```
SELECT o.pid, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cname) AS cusname, p.pname 
FROM orders AS o
JOIN customers AS c ON c.cid = o.cid
JOIN products AS p ON p.pid = o.pid
WHERE YEAR(o.odate) = 2014
GROUP BY pid
```

The result table is :

---

| pid | cusname | pname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith,Jones | chocolate |
| 2 | Jones,Jones,Gupta,Smith,Dupond | sugar |
| 3 | Jones,Smith,Dupond | milk |
| 4 | Blake,Jones,Gupta,Dupond,Blake | tea |

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for submitting an answer! This works perfectly well for me

Answer (score 0):

This should do. Do take into consideration that your expected output doesn't match with your sample data and what you wrote in question. i.e. for milk you have pairs dupond - jones and jones - smith, it seem sto me that dupond - smith should be present too. They both ordered same product and dupond < smith (I am guessing here that you are doing that comparison based on first letter of name)

```
SELECT
    c1.cname as c1name, c2.cname as c2name, p.pname
FROM 
    orders o1
    JOIN customers c1 on o1.cid = c1.cid
    JOIN orders o2 on o1.pid = o2.pid and o1.cid != o2.cid
    JOIN customers c2 on o2.cid = c2.cid
    join products p on o1.pid = p.pid
where 
    c1.cname < c2.cname
    and
    year(o1.odate) = 2014
    AND
    year(o2.odate) = 2014
GROUP BY
    c1.cname, c2.cname, p.pname
ORDER BY pname
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering and the previous precisions. I imagined the results as showing the pairs only once, which I assume was one of the reasons I couldn't find the answer, along with my total omission of the group by method. Have a good day and thank you again!

Comment: Your welcome! I would also advise you to [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on why you should accept/upvote answers that are helpful instead of using comments to thank people.